Add or remove 120 Ohm from the CAN circuit using Microcontroller
I want to design hardware circuit using microcontroller for CAN communication. One suggestion i require is i want to add 120 Ohm or remove it based on software configuration. I want to close the switch to add 120 Ohm and open the switch to remove it. How do i do it? I am planning to use the 5V relay.

As an alternative to a relay based solution, the Texas Instruments TIDA-01238
Controller Area Network (CAN) With Selectable Termination Reference Design  contains the following in the design guide which are relevant to the question:

TDA-01238 documents and tests two individual circuits that make termination selectable at individual CAN nodes, making termination at any node possible without modifying hardware. This allows for greater flexibility in CAN bus installations, since the location of the bus termination can be changed on the fly in order to optimize the performance of the bus.
Design Features

Selectable termination supporting wide input common mode range using opto-coupler technology
Selectable termination supporting standard input common mode range using MOSFETs


The Schematic — TIDA-01238 has the following for the two options:

Where:

U2 is the opto-coupler based solution. Note that R11 which is the termination resistor is 100 Ω rather than 120 Ω. Presumably this is to allow for the on resistance of the opto-coupler.
U4 and U3 are the MOSFET based solution. In this case R12 which is the termination resistor is 120 Ω.


Try this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
This should do the trick.

If i directly give GPIO output to the coil input of relay will it be ok? Do i need to add transistor also in the circuit?

If your coil current is less than the GPIO output current you can do without the transistor. Usually, this will not be the case: check the electrical specs of the microcontroller and relay coil current. Ideally, you want margin between these figures. In any case, the transistor is still recommended.

This is a bad idea, the CAN bus is too fast for a relay to toggle the lines in run-time.

@Lundin where are you seeing runtime requirements? The relay is perfectly suitable in an initialization routine.

@MOSFET How does every node on the bus know when every other node is done toggling their relay?

@Lundin Why is that even an assumption? I agree that chattering relays on a live bus is a terrible idea. But why would anybody want to do that in practice? After all the nodes are physically laid out, only the first and last node have to be closed. And that's it for the rest of the communication. I'm assuming Rajesh wants the relay for configurable bus termination, not node enable/disable.

Yes but how will you toggle the relays at all? If you toggle them from 2 MCU nodes during start up, how will node 1 know that node 2 is done toggling and vice versa? Are you synchronizing the power-on resets in some mysterious way? No, the only way to do it practically is trial & error, send some start-up message on the bus and pray that the bus will not go bus off, then in case it does, reset and try again. All of this for the purpose of insisting on an unsuitable component.

The reason I'm objecting is because I've seen this very design IRL where it was used on a wheel loader tractor with regular "car relays" and the result was that they occasionally killed the whole bus in very inconvenient ways due to bus off. I fixed it by replacing the relay with a faster SSR in that case, but an analog switch is the best option.

@Lundin I'm sorry. But I'm interpreting "i want to add 120 Ohm or remove it based on software configuration" as a means of bus termination controlled in FW. Your interpreting that as some sort of "bus gating" or node enable/disable. You say "If you toggle them from 2 MCU nodes during start up, how will node 1 know that node 2 is done toggling and vice versa?" They don't. And it won't matter. Has nothing to do with relay speed cause there is no toggling during broadcasts.

You don't seem to understand the root problem: how does any node on this bus know when it is safe to send CAN messages without risking error frames?

@Lundin I was talking about terminating the physical bus. You're talking about the CAN protocol. CAN has arbitration for nodes to know when it's safe to finish broadcasting messages. Error handling is managed by the nodes/CAN as always irrespective of the bus termination. These ideas aren't related.

@MOSFET I'm talking about the physical bus. You still don't get it: the CAN lines will sit at 2.5V idle whether the bus is terminated or not. You/the CAN controller will not notice anything wrong with the bus until you start sending. Then the lack of termination will lead to reflections and error frames. Additionally, the relay electromechanical bouncing might cause further disturbances on the lines and those you might be able to detect if you feed the CAN lines to an ADC or such, but that would be an obscure design.

It's not a good idea to use relays for this, because that means that the MCU will have to toggle the relay at start-up. That does not work!
Lets assume a standard CAN bus using one of the higher baudrates like 1Mbit. An 11 bit identifier has 111 bits worst case. But lets say the average frame bit length on whatever frame we are using is 64 bits.

If we are to transmit such a frame it takes 1/1Mbit * 64 = 64us.
The toggle/bouncing time on a relay is somewhere around 20ms at best.
During 20ms of relay toggling, we can then transmit 312 frames.
These frames may not get sent correctly because the bus is not properly terminated. In which their bit length will be significantly shorter than some 64 bits because it will get cut short somewhere, followed by a 6 bit error frame.
As soon as there is a transmission error, the CAN controllers with automatically try to resend the frame again pretty much immediately.
127 errors means that nodes will start to go error passive and 127 more errors is bus off.
And then the bus is dead before the relay is even done toggling.

Even if we were to use longer frames and slower baudrates this still remains an issue because error frames are just 6 bits long. Sure, you can have each node rebooting once it hits bus off and then it will eventually work after a while. But that kind of "trial & error" at every single system boot-up is bad engineering.
The correct way to do something like this is to use an analog switch IC, which can switch significantly faster and with less impact on the lines, with no signal bouncing. Pretty much any such IC will work.

I think i can use TS5A3167 0.9-Ω 1-channel 1:1 SPST Analog Switch.

@rajesh Yeah that will probably work fine.

Funny how everyone down votes this without stating any reasons why. For the record, I have 20+ years of CAN bus design and troubleshooting experience.
